# Let ${f_n}\to f$ in $R$. Prove that for each $a < b$, the function $f$ is continuous at some point of $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis

The problem seems fairly easy, but the solution I found online uses baire category theorem. I was wondering whether my simple solution actually works. Consider $\chi_{[a.b]}f_n\to \chi_{[a.b]}f$. We are on finite measure thus, by egoroff the convergence is actually uniform on some subset of $[a,b]$. Uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, thus $f$ is continuous at some point (or even uncountably many) points in $[a,b]$

Comment: Your proof seems to suggest that the functions $f_n$ are continuous, which is not in the problem statement.  Indeed, you make a claim about "uniform limit of continuous functions" but I do not see a limit of continuous functions anywhere.  [Aside: It would be nice if the problem statement could be put into the body of the question, not just in the title]

Comment: Take $f_n=f$ for all $n$, where $f$ is a function that is discontinuous everywhere, to get a counter-example.

Comment: I think you must have $f_n$ continuous. Otherwise the counterexample of Michael comes in.

Comment: With $f_n$ assumed to be continuous, still, how does your proof apply? Suppose the convergence is uniform over almost all points of $[a,b]$, say, all points but the rationals.  So what? A function can be continuous when restricted to the domain of irrationals, but discontinuous everywhere on the domain of the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $f_n$'s are continuous.Your proof fails even then.The mistake is at then end. If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on  a set $E$ then the restriction of $f$ to $E$ is continuous on $E$ **w.r.t the relative topololgy** on $E$. This does not guarantee that  $f$ is continuous at points of $E$ when  $f$ is viewed as a function on  the real line.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I knew something was amiss!